# UITableView to fit its dynamic content?

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview, size

I have a table and I want to prevent its scrolling and resize it to fit its content instead.

There a lot of similar questions-answers but they are all about static tables.

My table has sections for rows with section headers. I hide or show section cells on click on this section's header.

```
CGRect frame = detailsTableView.frame;
frame.size.height = detailsTableView.contentSize.height;
detailsTableView.frame = frame;
```

As I understand it is code I need. But how and where to call it?

Comment: what r the contents in your tableview cell?

Comment: very various. The main problem is they can have `UITextView` and `UIWebView` which are already definde in xib and class, but may change their height according to their content size.

Comment: set the cell height dynamically so the UItableview automatically set its content size. There is no need to set tableview frame. It's automatically increase upto cell count. And also as per the cell height.

Comment: omg. I want to set `tableView.frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height`. Is it clear for you now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to set tableView frame in a click section view event.

I calculate a total table view height as a sum of its item heights and it has some troubles with animation. But as for the rest it works.